# Spring with Camunda - DB is not updated upon restart if the process is configured through beans

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, camunda

I have a Camunda process that is started periodically once 15 minutes which is configured using a CRON expression. I use the default configuration to connect to MariaDB with default [data source configuration](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.8/user-guide/spring-boot-integration/configuration/).

Camunda process `myProcess.bpmn` timer definition:

- The process is `starteble` and `executable`
- The Timer definition type is `Cycle` and Timer definition as `0 0 0 ? * * *`.

Based on the [The Job Executor documentation](https://blog.camunda.com/post/2019/10/job-executor-what-is-going-on-in-my-process-engine/) I observed this value is stored in the `ACT_RU_JOB` table in the `REPEAT_` column.

```
SELECT ID_, REPEAT_ from act_ru_job;

--------------------------------------------------------
| ID_                                  | REPEAT_       |
--------------------------------------------------------
| 0d1f49da-83a8-11ea-a61b-98fa9b04dfaf | 0 0 0 ? * * * |
--------------------------------------------------------
```

Changing the CRON expression right in `myProcess.bpmn` using Camunda Modeler and restarting the application updated this value in the database and the process orchestrator works with the new value.

**Problem**

As soon as I load this value dynamically from the application properties through beans, the new value from properties is loaded, **logged**, but not stored in the database and therefore Camunda works with the old one.

`application.properties` with a different random value: `process.timer: 1 2 3 ? * * *`

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
public class TimerConfiguration {

    @Value("${process.timer}") 
    private String timerExpression;

    @Bean
    public String timerExpression() {
        // the log truly logs 1 2 3 ? * * *
        log.info("Periodical timer expression has been configured to: {}", timerExpression);
        return timerExpression;
    }
}
```

Camunda process `myProcess.bpmn` timer definition ([Link to the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kh6D6.png)) uses a dynamic value as a timer definition:

```
${timerConfiguration.timerExpression()}
```

**Question**

How to make Camunda synchronize the configured data with the database it uses? No exception is thrown, the application continues with the old configuration from the database.

```
SELECT ID_, REPEAT_ from act_ru_job;
```

The query returns the old value. When the CRON expression is set manually right inside the `myProcess.bpmn` process, the value is updated after restart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick answer: Processes with a timer start event register on the process engine when the app is started (e.g. the process is deployed) ... so "timerExpression()" is only read once ...

I couldn't come up with a workaround yet ... besides redeploying the bpmn to re-register the timer ... which would make the concept of an expression based timer obsolete.

A non-bpmn solution could be to use an ordinary scheduler bean that just starts a process via runtimeService API and do not use a timer start event at all.

Comment: Sounds logical, thanks for the answer. Are you a developer of Camunda or a more experienced user?

Comment: Some kind of contributor, but not officially associated with camunda.